# Sitecore Rocks 2.1.89.0 connection error to Sitecore 9.1.0

Tags: sitecore-rocks

When I try to connect to my sitecore 9.1.0 instance with Sitecore Rocks 2.1.89 I catch a weird error:

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If
>   using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method
>   is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '
>    ...

[image]

But when I connect to another sitecore 9.1.0 website - it works good.

What is wrong with my first instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that:

1. you able to rich out your sitecore instance by `http` protocol
2. site https binding "`Require Server Name Indication`" setting is unchecked
3. you don't have any URL Rewrite rules for redirect from `http` to `https`

After all these steps you can create a new connection:

[image]

Just checked it on my local env on the same Sitecore 9.1.0 instance and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I was really because of redirecting to https